# Python KeyError scanning list of hosts for open ports

Tags: python, list, nmap, port-scanning

I have a list of my ip's in my python script, and I'm trying to run a nmap scan on each of them to find open ports. I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rscan.py", line 33, in <module>
    main()
  File "rscan.py", line 30, in main
    vulnscan(nm, L)
  File "rscan.py", line 6, in vulnscan
    for port in nm[item].all_tcp():
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/nmap/nmap.py", line 567, in __getitem__
KeyError: u'IP ADDRESS HERE'
```

(There is an actual ip address in the "IP ADDRESS HERE" part, though.)

The scanning part of my code that I tried is is:

```
for item in L:
        for port in nm[item].all_tcp():
            state= nm[item]['tcp'][port]['state']
            if state== 'open':
                print state
```

'L' is the list that contains my ip addresses.

What is the proper way to scan a small list of ip addresses for open ports using nmap?

Comment: What package are you using? Where's the rest of your code where you actually tell it what ips and ports to scan? If this is it, you probably aren't using it correctly, but I can only assume you're using python-nmap.

Comment: The other parts of my script just collect my ip addresses and put them into the list. This is all I have as far as scanning the ports goes. I'm missing something important, yeah?

Comment: I assume you're using python-nmap? Check out the usage section on how to use it properly http://xael.org/norman/python/python-nmap/#usage

Comment: silly error on my part, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this, based on your code:

```
for item in L:
    if item in nm.all_hosts():
        for port in nm[item].all_tcp():
            state = nm[item]['tcp'][port]['state']
            if state == 'open':
                print state
```

Checking if specified `ip` address is in `nm.all_hosts()` (which returns a list of `ips`) allows you to safely query `nm[item]` afterwards.

Note that you could make this code a bit cleaner by simply intersecting your L list with the list of ip addresses returned by nm.all_hosts():

```
items = list(set(L) & set(nm.all_hosts()))

for item in items:
    for port in nm[item].all_tcp():
        state = nm[item]['tcp'][port]['state']
        if state == 'open':
            print state
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. When I try that, I get "PortScanner object has no attribute "get"

Comment: forget my previous comment, I'm going to check this

Comment: I'm not getting an error now! :D Now the problem is that it doesn't seem to be scanning the ports.. it just scans one or two each time, then the script ends.

Comment: oh ok... I don't really know what to do then. Have you checked that the ports you think are open are really open?

Comment: To test it out, I modified the code to print closed if the ports are closed. Whenever I run the scan, depending on the number of hosts I scan, I just get one or two closed ports. Shouldn't it be scanning ALL the tcp ports for each host in the list?

Comment: This I don't know and couldn't be of much help. You should ask another question related to this topic. As far as I'm concerned this current question is solved now (your `KeyError`)